# Ubuntu as VPN gateway for local LAN

Tags: openvpn, routing, gateway

I'm running Ubuntu 23.10. On it I've established a VPN connection to my remote HQ with an route set in .ovpn as follows:

```
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

From Ubuntu itself, I can access and ping hosts in 192.168.1. network with no issues at all.

I now wanted for all other hosts that are in the same network as Ubuntu to be able to access the remote HQ network as well. For that I thought it is enough to enabled IP4 forwarding on Ubuntu host, so I did enabled `net.ipv4.ip_forward=1` in /etc/sysctl.conf and run 'sysctl -p' to make it active.

I then set routing table on the clients so that 192.168.1. gets sent to Ubuntu host rather than the default gw.

But, when I attempt to ping any host in the remote HQ network from any other client than Ubuntu, I'm getting "Network is unreachable".

What am I missing?

```
% ping 192.168.1.10
PING 192.168.1.10 (192.168.1.10): 56 data bytes
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
ping: sendto: Network is unreachable
```

Comment: I'm assuming that the remote network is `192.168.1.0/24` and that your local network is _not_ also `192.168.1.0/24` (it would help if you specified the network addresses in your question). Your Ubuntu is now the router for traffic from your LAN to the remote LAN. _Your_ machines know how to get there (because you told them in their routing tables): send packets to your router who forwards them. Now ask yourself how the machines in the remote network could know how to send response packets back to your network. You didn't change _their_ routing tables. You will need to NAT on your router.

Comment: For clarity: if your local network were _also_ `192.168.1.0/24`, then the machines at either side of your router surely couldn't find each other, because they'd mistakenly think they were in the same "physical" LAN.

Comment: You are correct @zwets, NAT was missing. Thank you!